# Gradle cannot find theme

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to simply build a second module in my Android project. I have refered to another module, because there are some Activities and classes I want to reuse. This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.minerall.sapphire.browser"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "MissingTranslation"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':sapphirelib')
    compile project(path: ':app')
}
```

The `build.gradle` of `sapphirelib` is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
    compile project(path: ':Zebra_SDK_DS3678')
}
```

And of `app`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        demo {
            keyAlias 'FlexDemo'
            keyPassword '******'
            storeFile file('/path/to/file.jks')
            storePassword '******'
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
        full {
            keyAlias 'PocketFull'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('/path/to/file.jks')
            storePassword '*****'
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    productFlavors {
        full {
            applicationId "nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.full"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.full
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Sapphire Pocket"
            versionCode 13
            versionName "Flex 2.0.25"
        }
        demo {
            applicationId "nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.demo"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.demo
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Pocket Demo"
            versionCode 12
            versionName "Flex 1.13 DEMO"
        }
        ipsdemo {
            applicationId "nl.minerall.sapphire.pocket.ipsdemo"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.demo
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Pocket IPS Demo"
            versionCode 12
            versionName "Flex 1.13 IPS DEMO"
        }
        sourceSets.ipsdemo.root = "src/demo"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "MissingTranslation"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':sapphirelib')
}
```

When I build, I get the error

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar'.

and I am thrown into a `values-v21.xml` file that is apparently auto-generated. The `styles.xml` I am using is:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It completely beats me where the `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar` comes from ...

Comment: Show your two other build gradle files, please

Comment: You should increase your compileSdk if you want that resource... It doesn't have to match the targetSdk

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't necesarily want to use that resource. Both the `app` and `sapphirelib` compiled just fine, until I added the `sapphirebrowser` module. I have raised `compileSdk` now, and I get another error...

Comment: Okay, and what's that error? Secondly, you don't need a JAR for the simple xml. `compile group: 'org.simpleframework', name: 'simple-xml', version: '2.7.1'`

Comment: @cricket_007 the other error was a color that wasn't found. I removed it from `styles.xml` and it runs past that one now. I am slowly getting there... :)

Comment: I see sapphirelib uses `compileSdkVersion 24`, so why don't the other modules? Also, while I think you should use support v7 libraries instead, the version of `support-v4:19.1.0'`needs to match the compileSdk